# How to get the default value from PARAMDESC

Tags: c#, com, interop

I am using the `ITypeInfo` interface to obtain information about COM objects and their members (in order to build some kind of reflection API). Reading types and members (and their parameters) works fine, but I don´t know how to access a parameter´s default value. This is what I have...

```
...

PARAMDESC paramDesc = elemDesc.desc.paramdesc;

object defaultValue = null;
PARAMFLAG paramFlags = paramDesc.wParamFlags;
bool hasDefaultValue = (paramFlags & PARAMFLAG.PARAMFLAG_FHASDEFAULT) == PARAMFLAG.PARAMFLAG_FHASDEFAULT;
if (hasDefaultValue && paramDesc.lpVarValue != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    defaultValue = null; // TODO: get value from paramDesc.lpVarValue
}

...
```

I check the `wParamFlags` field; if the parameter has a default value and the `lpVarValue` field has a valid pointer, I would like to read that value. I assumed that `lpVarValue` is pointing to a native COM variant, so I tried to get an object representing the default value using `Marshal.GetObjectForNativeVariant`, but this fails with a fatal error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They took a shortcut on the PARAMDESC.lpVarValue because the pointer type is hard to declare in managed code.  It is actually a pointer to PARAMDESCEX, declared like this in oaidl.idl:

```
typedef struct tagPARAMDESCEX {
    ULONG cBytes;               /* size of this structure */
    VARIANTARG varDefaultValue; /* default value of this parameter */
} PARAMDESCEX, * LPPARAMDESCEX;
```

So, yes, using Marshal.GetObjectForNativeVariant() is a good way to get the *varDefaultValue* field.  You however have to add to skip the *cBytes* field.  That takes adding 4 to skip the ULONG and an extra 4 to skip the padding between the fields.  So use something like:

```
PARAMDESC pd = ...;
object defValue = null;
if ((pd.wParamFlags & 0x20) != 0) {
    IntPtr defptr = new IntPtr((long)pd.lpVarValue + 8);
    defValue = Marshal.GetObjectForNativeVariant(defptr);
}
```

Comment: This solution works. The only thing I changed is the pointer offset... isn´t ulong an 8-byte integer?

Comment: No, its 4 bytes.  Both in 32-bit and 64-bit modes.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about alignment.  It is likely to insert padding between cBytes and varDefaultValue to keep the variant aligned.

Comment: I checked with the C++ compiler, there extra padding of 4 in both 32-bit and 64-bit code.  So hardcoding 8 is indeed the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221019.aspx) for `PARAMFLAG_FHASDEFAULT` says:

> Parameter has default behaviors defined. The pPARAMDescEx field contains a pointer to a VARIANT that describes the default value for this parameter, if the PARAMFLAG_FOPT and PARAMFLAG_FHASDEFAULT bit of wParamFlags is set.

So, so long as both `PARAMFLAG_FOPT` and `PARAMFLAG_FHASDEFAULT` are set, you can read the information out of `paramDesc.pPARAMDescEx`.

---

But according to the answer from @Hans, this is actually `PARAMDESCEX` rather than `PARAMDESC` and hence my confusion.